# Warning : configuration file not found

Tags: linux, kali-linux, uefi

I just made a bootable usb drive with kali linux 2016.1 (rolling) with `dd` command. After booting in the usb drive it gives me this thing : `Warning : configuration file not found`. I can select configuration file from `/EFI/boot`.
I looked in my usb drive with gparted and i saw an unknown partition + fat16 partiton(EFI).

P.S I have uefi bios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here after searching the internet :
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux